# Why does all permissions need to be asked before app is shown in settings?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, permissions

My application is tracking a user and allowing them to create annotations/markers with information/images stored in them.
This is my info.plist permission usages.

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>info</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>info</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>info</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>info</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>info</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>info</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

The user is directly asked for location permission WhenInUseUsage to show their position on the map. Then when user wants to start tracking their position i ask for AlwaysUsage permission and prompt them to the apps settings screen. At this stage it will not find the apps settings screen.

I have tried to reinstall my application, restarting phone, other phones etc. Only when i also ask for camera permission will app show up in settings screen. I would only want to ask for photo permission when the user is actually going to use it for context of why i am asking.

This is how i ask for permissions inside settings:

```
func showSettingsAlert(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: C.Alert.settingsTitle, message: C.Alert.settingsMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: C.Alert.setting, style: .default, handler: { action in
        
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: C.Alert.cancel, style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is this intended? Should all permission need to be asked at start of runtime before i can send user to apps settings screen? What have i missed?

Comment: You should not direct the user to settings for this use case anyway. There is a difference between "always" location permission (which the user needs to grant) and background location (which your app can use without always permission).  The correct approach is simply to ask for always permission when you need it and also enable background location on your location manager. Your app will receive provisional always permission, you will get location in the background and the user will be prompted to grant you true always after some time. There is a wwdc 2019 session on this

Comment: @Paulw11 I did not know this. It is clearly the correct way of doing it. Even though this is not the answer to my question i hope people read this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to direct the user to the settings panel before asking for any permission, you could add a Settings.bundle to your project. This will make sure, that the settings panel is available directly after installation.

---

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't get what you're trying to do in first place..

Each permissions will only appear in the settings after you requested it in your app.
You should ask the user for each permission in a context, where the user tries to use a feature, where this permission is required. The user should be able to understand, why you are requesting this permission.
So it isn't a good approach to ask all your permissions at start of your app.

For example:
Ask for location, when the user opens a map and wants to see his position.
Ask for camera permission, when the user taps the "scan QRCode" button or "take photo" button.
Etc..

Comment: That is exactly how i currently ask for permissions in the app. I only ask when it is going to be used. The problem is when i need to ask for location in background. I send the user to app settings. But they will not reach app settings before i also ask for photo permissions. I do not want to ask for photo permission before its use. App settings does not show before booth location whenInUse and camera is asked. Users should be able to reach app settings and choose location alwaysUsage before asked about camera(They might not ever need/want to use camera)

Comment: Then maybe try the settings.bundle approach. With this, the settings will be available for sure.